# Screenshots in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, canvas, screenshot

Is it possible to do screenshot of video/video stream in angular 2/4?
I have heard about html2canvas but when I used it, the video was not on the screen. All the other solutions were for angularjs and I cant rewrite it to work on angular 2/4.

I want to achieve this 
[effect](https://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/video-canvas-screenshot.html).

Comment: Late reply but I have used html2canvas successfully with angular 4 so I can say with confidence that it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but you could accomplish this without the html2canvas with Vanilla JS.

Checkout this demo to see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-video-player-snapshot

Note: Due to CORS issues, video only streams after downloading the app and running it locally.